# Do Python sockets only work on LAN?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I've been able to connect computers that are connected to the same network using Python's `socket`. I'm wondering if it's possible to connect computers on different networks (say, a friend who lives far away).

If it's possible, I have some additional questions:

- Are there any changes that need to be made to the code?
- What IP address does the client (who lives far away) use?

Comment: You need to learn a bit on how networks work. It's entirely possible of course, but you'll probably need to have port forwarding in your router setup (and/or your friend's)

Comment: I propose to close the question as too broad. The OP is missing the basics of how system communicate in LAN and WAN, i.e. about how systems gets addressed, what routing is etc. This has nothing to do with sockets at all.